# Stuck at "Updates and other software" installing Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on HP Spectre x360

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS so I can set up a dual-boot with Windows 10 on my HP Spectre x360 (model 13-aw2018ca). Initially, I tried installing using a live USB and it seemed to have completed successfully, however GRUB did not appear on boot and I was unable to actually access Ubuntu. So, I tried following other instructions/tutorials online, over the course of which the original installation was lost. Now, when I attempt to install Ubuntu, everything works up to the "Updates and other software" screen. When I press Continue the installer freezes and the cursor turns into a spinning wheel. I have tried letting this continue for 1 hour, and have tried unmounting and mounting the Windows partition as recommended at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1766978, however this does not cause the installer to become unstuck. On starting up the live USB, I also see an ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS in the console as seen in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o9bB.jpg).

I have Secure Boot, Optane Memory, Fast Boot and Hibernate all disabled, and I have turned off BitLocker encryption. This model does not have an Nvidia graphics card, so I do not believe it is an issue with graphics drivers. I have also tried installing without Wi-Fi and unchecking the "download updates while installing Ubuntu" option. I am new to Linux and dual-booting, so any help on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much, and let me know if there are any more details I can provide!

Update: I have tried installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and the installer got stuck in a similar place, right before it was about to show the available partitions on the disk. Since both installers freeze at this point, I am wondering if there is some issue with the partitions on my drive. However, I am able to see all of the partitions in Disks and Gparted before and during the installation. None of the partitions seem to have any issues, other than the 16MB Microsoft Reserved Partition which has a red exclamation mark next to it, however it seems that this is expected.

Comment: Did you verify the ISO download before flashing to USB?  Have you tried another USB?  Is the installation media valid and does it pass integrity checks?

Comment: @Nmath Yes, I verified the download using SHA256 following the steps on the Ubuntu website, and I have tried with two USBs and they both cause the same issue. The installation media does pass the file checks that occur when the USB first boots, but other than that I haven't tried any checks on the USBs themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting the Ubuntu folder on the EFI partition and trying the installation again. This time I was able to install Linux successfully!